# Where do HDL (Verilog) questions belong?

Tags: discussion

Questions asking about how HDL constructs relate/imply hardware or vice versa, I think belong on Electronics.

Question about testbenches, compiler errors feel like programming questions to me, and StackOverflow already does a good job of answering them, [Verilog Qs on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=verilog%20is%3aquestion).

**Example questions I think could be migrated** :

- [Testbench connectivity issues](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60724/13513)
- [Incorrect ideas on how the simulator works](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60765/13513)
- [Closed Testbench issue](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/60712/13513)

I would like some guidelines on this topic as I see a number of posts which I think would get better answers on StackOverflow, but do not want to unnecessarily/incorrectly flag them.

**Update**
Based on the The Photons feedback I understand that downvotes on meta are against the idea, not the question. From the down votes against migrating questions implies the community welcomes HDL based questions.

Comment: Related: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2622/17592

Comment: Downvotes on meta don't mean your question was poorly asked. They mean people disagree with your proposal (to migrate some questions to SO).

Comment: Thanks @The Photon, I was only wanting to know if that was what the community wanted todo. Most questions I have answered here on Verilog end up getting migrated to SO. I though it was a community effort to separate out programming syntax issues from hardware related issues.

Comment: @CamilStaps Thanks for pointing me to that question, ThePhotons [answer there](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/2627/13513) is good and looks like it applies across the board to cross over topics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are a boundary that is on topic on both sites, as such I feel we should allow users to choose where they ask and keep the questions there.